# Как переместить объект с Rect Transform

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, у меня есть кнопка, когда на неё происходит нажатие, и она телепортируется по координатам.

Что она успешно НЕ делает, а растягивается по левой и правой стороне, либо ничего не делает, либо улетает по переменной Z (Всё зависит от переменных которые я задаю)

сам я пробовал разные методы и даже через обычный transform, но всё четно

```
public RectTransform MainButton

public void ButtonSuperClick()
{
   MainButton.offsetMin += new Vector2(-50, 0);            
}
```

Comment: Причем тут вообще `offsetMin`? [Документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html) открой для разнообращия. За позицию на `Canvas`, в `RectTransform` отвечает `anchoredPosition` типа `Vector2`. Ось `z` на `Canvas` роли вообще не играет, элементы отрисовываются по очереди согласно иерархии.

Comment: Я так сделал изначально и документацию удивитесь читал, но как я уже сказал в своём ответе, это была ошибка со стороны юнити.
Так как нужный мне объект САМ перемещался по координате Z, не было ни одной строчки кода которая бы за это отвечала, а после того как я перезапустил в проект, меня и вовсе откатила на часа 4 работы. 

Сейчас сделал так чтобы нужный мне объект перемещался рандомно к другим, невидимым объектам, что мне и нужно было изначально.

Всего доброго <3

Answer (score -2):

Сам нашел ответ, у меня проект в юнити навернулся, из-за чего объект улетал на координату z -12800

Но если кому нужно перемещение кнопки, я его сделал на перемещение объекта к объекту `public uint IdStyle = 1;

```
public Transform pointOne;
public Transform pointTwo;
public Transform pointTree;
public Transform pointFour;



public double t = 0;
public double tM = 0.5;



void Update()
{
    
    if (IdStyle == 3)
    {
        t = t + Time.deltaTime;
        int a = Random.Range(1, 4);
        if (t >= tM)
        {
          switch (a)
            {
                case 1: transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointOne.position, 100f); t = 0; break;
                case 2: transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointTwo.position, 100f); t = 0; break;
                case 3: transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointTree.position, 100f); t = 0; break;
                case 4: transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, pointFour.position, 100f); t = 0; break;
            }

        
        }

       
    }
}`
```